# Regex related confusion

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract **mkghj.bmg** and **pp.kp** from the following string using a regex used in javascript

```
avb@gh.lk mkghj.bmg ,,,,fsdsdf.fdfd pllk.kp sdfsdf.bb,,,, pp.kp
```

Everything enclosed within ,,,, needs to be ignored. There could be multiple instances of ,,,, But they will always occur even number of times (non occurrence is also a possibility) in the string.

Also, avb@gh.lk has an @ sign, therefore it needs to be ignored

I guess the rule I am looking for is this - if there is a dot (.) look ahead and look behind :-

1. If the dot is enclosed inside ,,,, then ignore it
2. If the dot has an @ before it with no space between the dot and @, ignore it
3. In all other cases, capture an unbroken set of characters (until a space is encountered) on either side of the dot

I came up with this regex, but it is not helpful

```
[^\, ]+([^@ \,]+\w+)[^\, ]+
```

Comment: on what rules you're selecting these two values ?

Comment: Can you mention some rationale for selecting those strings? Why you don't want to select `pllk.kp` which is similar to the string you want?

Comment: Because pllk.kp is enclosed inside ,,,,

Comment: you could just do `\b(mkghj.bmg )|(pp.kp)\b`

Comment: The example is just for illustration purpose, I would like to get something generic

Comment: Then I agree with @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi you need to describe some pattern to base the regex off of

Comment: Why not extract avb@gh.lk?

Comment: @vjjj `^[^ ]+ ([^ ]+) ,,,,.*,,,,\s+(.*)` like that? https://regex101.com/r/bhWwrz/1

Comment: avb@gh.lk has an @ sign, need to ignore that as well

Comment: @vjjj the above regex does ignore avb@gh.lk it only is capturing two groups and they are the two things you wanted.

Comment: @abc123 please have a look at -https://regex101.com/r/tZyaCH/1/ I would like to get 4 groups as matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking that is (mind the capturing group):

```
not_this | neither_this_nor_this | (but_this_interesting_stuff)
```

---

For your specific example, this could be

```
,,,,.*?,,,,|\S+@\S+|(\S+)
```

You need to check for the existance of group 1, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FM5MJZ/3/).

---

In `JS` this would be:

```js
var myString = "avb@gh.lk mkghj.bmg ,,,,fsdsdf.fdfd pllk.kp sdfsdf.bb,,,, pp.kp";
var myRegexp = /,,,,.*?,,,,|\S+@\S+|(\S+)/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    if (typeof(match[1]) != 'undefined') {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Comment: I would make one small change in your regex: ,,,,.*?,,,,|\S+@\S+|(\S+\.\S+)

Comment: @vjjj: Go for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/bhWwrz/1)

```
^[^ ]+ ([^ ]+) ,,,,.*,,,,\s+(.*)
```

### Description

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
    Match a single character not present in the list below [^ ]+
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
      matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
    1st Capturing Group ([^ ]+)
        Match a single character not present in the list below [^ ]+
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
          matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
     ,,,, matches the characters  ,,,, literally (case sensitive)
    .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
        * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    ,,,, matches the characters ,,,, literally (case sensitive)
    \s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    2nd Capturing Group (.*)
        .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
```

Comment: could you please check - https://regex101.com/r/tZyaCH/1 I would like to get 4 groups as matches

Comment: @vjjj i think you forgot to press enter at the end of the first line so it could match the two lines correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string between `,,,` by '' and than from remaining you can split and search for `@` sign and filter.

```js
let str = `avb@gh.lk mkghj.bmg ,,,,fsdsdf.fdfd pllk.kp sdfsdf.bb,,,, pp.kp`

let op = str.replace(/,,,.*?,,,,|/g,'').split(' ').filter(e=> !e.includes('@') && e );

console.log(op)
```